# "value" attribute of node/element in Dartlang

Tags: dart

for the below code, I got an error "There is no such getter 'value' in 'Element'":

```
var q = theQty.shadowRoot.children[1].shadowRoot.children[0].value;
print(q);
```

but the below code worked very fine:

```
var q = theQty.shadowRoot.children[1].shadowRoot.children[0];
print(q.value);
```

I did not understand why, and what is the different between the 2 statements.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `Element` doesn't have a `value` property, but the specific element you have does, and the `var` is casting the object as `dynamic` which stops the error.

You can test this by changing `var` to `dynamic` and see if it stills works, then change it to `Element` and see if it fails.

However, this seems somewhat confusing to me, I would be expect `var` to infer the type, so these would not behave differently :/